# I get CS0310 for using new constraint, but I need it

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

```
public async Task LoadObjectsCacheAsync<T>(params T[] objs) where T : new(), IStoreableObject
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await con.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        foreach (var obj in objs)
        {
            if (await SendScalarAsync<int>($"SELECT COUNT(Id) From {obj.TableName};", con).ConfigureAwait(false) != 0)
            {
                var ids = YieldData<ulong>($"SELECT Id FROM {obj.TableName};", con).ToImmutableArray();
                foreach (var id in ids)
                {
                    var newObj = await LoadObjectAsync(new T() { Id = id }).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(newObj.Id)) Cache.TryAdd(newObj.Id, newObj);
                    else Cache[newObj.Id] = newObj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the issue is, I can't actually add multiple objects, for example:

```
await LoadObjectsCacheAsync(new Foo());
await LoadObjectsCacheAsync(new Bar());
```

Works, but...

```
IStoreableObject[] objs = {new Foo(), new Bar()};
await LoadObjectsCacheAsync(objs);
```

Doesn't

```
Error   CS0310  'IStoreableObject' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLExpressClient.LoadObjectsCacheAsync<T>(params T[])'
```

This will only work if I remove `new` constraint on the method, but I need it for the cache, otherwise, all objects added to the cache will reference the same object (already tested and didn't work for what it is supposed to do), Does anyone have any idea of how can I fix it? I tried reading 2 questions related to this, but neither actually had the answer I needed. I also tried creating a dummy struct to get rid of `new` constraint, but it doesn't work as intended as the method `LoadObjectAsync` will only load the Id and Name of the struct, object's properties don't get loaded as they don't exists in the dummy struct. I will appreciate any help

Comment: `T` can only be one type and interfaces cannot have constructors, so you'll have to make separate calls for different concrete types.  Alternatively you could pass in  objects and a `Funct<T>` that creates the object for you like `LoadObjectsCacheAsync(params (Entity : T, Create : Func<T>)[] objs)` and call it like `LoadObjectsCacheAsync<IStoreableObject>((new Foo(), () => new Foo()), (new Bar(), () => new Bar()));`  Then instead of `new T()` you'd use `objs[i].Create();`

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast answer, I feared it wasn't going to be possible in the way I wanted, yet this work-around seems to be a bit complicated as this method is for a public library. Atm the easiest work around I found was `foreach(var obj in objs) await LoadObjectsCacheAsync(obj);` but I actually expected a way to provide all objects at once. But since it seems not to be possible at all... Or at least not with `new` constraint, which is a must for the method :/

Comment: I found a possible work around, using Reflection, I can create a new instance of T and modify its Id

Comment: Would adding a method `CreateNewObject` to `IStorableObject` work as it seem you want to create objects of the same type as the original object. That function would create an empty object of the desired type?

Comment: Sorry for late response, Yea that's a possibility, but since I only need it for a single method I decided to create an instance of T with Activator, works like charm. Thanks for the help